# How to vlookup/hlookup in microsoft excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a relatively simple formula that I can not figure out.
I need to use B1 and B6 to return a value in B7.

B1 needs to match the value in row 12. Then using only that column of the matched value, it needs to search the numbers below to match B6 (or the closest value). Once that number is found, it needs to return correct value in column C.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You deleted your column and row numbers, what appears to be col B only has rows 1,2,3.  You need a different screenshot.

Comment: @Tyson ok i think the screenshot has been updated. let me know if that helps! thank you!

Comment: This REVERS LOOKUP `=VLOOKUP(B6,CHOOSE({1,2},F13:F22,C13:C22),2,0)` will also find the value `80`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDEX(C13:C22,MATCH(B6,INDEX(D13:N22,0,MATCH(B1,D12:N12,0)),0))
```

[image: POC]

It uses MATCH and INDEX instead of HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect new understanding of the question.  I originally thought you were trying to pull a number from the middle of the table, not the left most column.  That has been corrected.

Comment: you are the man that worked like a charm!